# Remove 'Activities' folders: "Sundry" and "suse-yast.directory"

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Yesterday I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 and when I decided to reorganize the activities' folders, I've found these pre-existing with none application assigned. **How I could remove them?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
```

This should list all the app-folders currently in use.

Run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children []
```

to remove them all.

You may have to restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or re-login to see the effect.

Comment: I've just tried this before, but I continue seeing them.

Comment: edit:  I had just to restart the gnome-shell : alt + f2 and type "r".

Comment: @MarcoD.G. Thanks for the info, I've appended to the answer.

Comment: This answer could be further improved if an example were added that demonstrated how to remove a single, specific, empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Appfolders Management extension" by Maestroschan to manage these folders (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/). Install this extension using whatever method you prefer, and then in the applications view, you can add shortcuts to any of the default folders, or create new ones. If you right click on a folder, you can choose to delete that folder, which kicks all the shortcuts inthat folder back to the default applications view. Once you disable the extension, the changes are still in place. For example, I deleted the 'suse-yast.directory' folder by adding an app to that folder, then selecting that folder, and deleting it. All the other folders I like (Games, Office, Utilities) remain in place.